# Can we use web servlets and servlet filters in Spring Webflux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlets

I want to migrate from Spring MVC to Spring Webflux but there are some servlet filters and web servlets that I used from 3rd parties and must be migrated to their equivalent Webflux version.

But this is not practicable because they are from 3rd party frameworks.
 For example: H2 server `WebServlet` and `MetricsServlet` and `InstrumentedFilter`.

Is there any way to convert a servlet or servlet filter to its equivalent Webflux version?

Comment: No there isn't... The servlet stuff is based on a standardized API, there is no such thing for reactive implementations., not to mention the whole technology stack is different. Although you might be able to bolt something on, it would basically make your reactive part useless as that bolted on thing would need to be blocking (due to the API design of the servlet stack).

Answer (score 0):

You can use tomcat as webflux implementation (you can do this by excluding netty starter and including tomcat starter).

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

You can add servlet filters by creating `WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory>` bean and adding filters through `Context` interface. For example:

```java
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatReactiveWebServerFactory> customizer() {
    return factory -> factory.addContextCustomizers(
            context -> {

                FilterDef filterDef = new FilterDef();
                filterDef.setFilterName("name");
                filterDef.setFilter(new SomeFilter());

                FilterMap filterMap = new FilterMap();
                filterMap.setFilterName("name");
                filterMap.addURLPattern("/url/pattern");

                context.addFilterMap(filterMap);
                context.addFilterDef(filterDef);
            }
    );
}
```

Default name of tomcat Servlet when configured as webflux "implementation" is `httpHandlerServlet`